# Django HyperlinkedRelatedField read_only False gives queryset Error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Dog model has a field "cat'

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    ...
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat)
    ...

class CatSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):      
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        # Replace ID with SLUG in urls
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        fields = ('url', 'slug')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

class DogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    cat= serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='cat-detail',
        lookup_field='slug',
        many=False,
        read_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ('url', 'slug', 'cat')
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
           'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

---

```
class CatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['slug'] = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return context
    queryset = Cat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CatSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

class DogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Dog.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    serializer_class = DogSerializer
```

---

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cats', rest_views.CatViewSet)
router.register(r'dogs', rest_views.DogViewSet)
```

---

How can I set:

```
read_only=False
```

The error I get when I set it to False is:

> 'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
>   AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat= serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='cat-detail',
    lookup_field='slug',
    many=False,
    read_only=False,
    queryset=Cat.objects.all()
)
```

This worked just fine.